# Unable to determine the correct call signature for {procedure name} - package name should be specified separately using '.withCatalogName("PARAMS")'

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, procedure, spring-jdbc

I have java code to execute store procedure like in below :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {SQLException.class, Exception.class })
public void executeSPForInsertData(DataSource ds,String procedureName,Map<String, Object> inputParameter){
    //PARAMS.PKG_PARA_UPLD_VAL.PR_SP_FAHMI
    String[] inParam = inputParameter.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("P_T_TABLE_UPLD_EXCEL",inputParameter);

    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(paramsDataSourceBean)
                              .withProcedureName(procedureName);

    String[] path = procedureName.split(".");
    if (path.length >= 2) {
        jdbcCall.withSchemaName(path[0]);
        jdbcCall.withCatalogName(path[1]);
        jdbcCall.withProcedureName(path[2]);
    }
    Map<String,Object> outputParameter = jdbcCall.execute(in);
}
```

When i run, there is this error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature for PARAMS.PKG_PARA_UPLD_VAL.PR_SP_FAHMI - package name should be specified separately using '.withCatalogName("PARAMS")'
```

Comment: Does the procedure is within a package?

Comment: Yes, procedure is within a package.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Spring 5.x, Java 8, Oracle DB)

Assuming you have a stored procedure named MY_PROC in package PKG1

```
//Consturct SqlParameter/SqlOutParameter
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
parameters.add(new SqlParameter("param_x", Types.VARCHAR));
// ...add all the required SqlParameter here(optional params can be skipped if you wish) .
// SqlOutParameter, SqlInOutParameter can also be added here as per your requirement

// Construct the SimpleJdbcCall
final SimpleJdbcCall call =
    new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcUtil.getJdbcTemplate()).withCatalogName("PKG1")
    .withProcedureName("MY_PROC")
    //.withSchemaName("YOUR_SCHEME_NAME")
    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
    .withNamedBinding()
    .declareParameters(parameters.stream().toArray(SqlParameter[]::new));


// ConstructParameterSource
final MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("param_x", "value");
// ...add all the required named param values here

Map<String, Object> result = call.execute(paramSource);
```